Enable buildkit for run Symbony in Docker
I want to learn Symfony. I want to run the project with this -> https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker. Problem is that all the time if I send command docker compose build --no-cache, I have the error

Step 9/19 : COPY --link --chmod=755 frankenphp/docker-entrypoint.sh
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint the --chmod option requires BuildKit.
Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/buildkit/ to learn how to build
images with BuildKit enabled ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build :
Build failed
I tryed enable BuildKit. In my computer I created file /etc/docker/daemon.json with this json

{
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}

And I restarted Docker deamon
sudo systemctl restart docker
Daemon was restarted but all the time I have this error. Any idea?
